# Setting Up Dell XPS 14 Ultrabook for Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, dell, uefi

I've just bought an XPS 14 Ultrabook with Windows 8 and I'd like to set up dual boot with the latest LTS Ubuntu, however i cannot figure out how to do it from a USB drive!

I've seen this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166513/install-ubuntu-12-04-64bits-on-dell-xps-14-ultrabook) but it doesn't explain how i should set up the boot section of my BIOS, Legacy or UEFI etc.

When i go into Boot Options at start up i don't see USB as an option - if i go into BIOS and switch from UEFI to Legacy and then go into my boot menu and select USB (now an option), i get an error. I've read that I shouldn't even need to use LEgacy but its the only way to get the USB boot option.

I really need an Idiots Guide! I've dual booted before from a USB on other windows PCs but this has me stumped - and i really don't want to be stuck with Windows 8!

I hope someone can help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic thing you need to do are disabling the UEFI,Intel Rapid Start (if any),and Secure boot.and also there is similiar case to you here

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

just jump directly to the top answer.it will help,a lot

Comment: Just had a quick skim through but that looks very helpful. Will try it this afternoon and report back :)

Comment: ***DO NOT*** disable (U)EFI support! With Windows booting in (U)EFI mode, disabling that support will at best have no effect (it's often not actually disabled, just set to lower priority), and at worst you'll end up with a BIOS-mode Linux installation that must then be fixed with Boot Repair or something else.

Answer (score 0):

[My Web page on Linux EFI-mode installs](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) may be helpful. It's not Ubuntu-specific, but it should help you understand the principles involved and steer you around some of the common pitfalls.

[The Ubuntu wiki's page on EFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) may also be helpful. It's more Ubuntu-specific than my page.

If you're not able to boot a medium in EFI mode, then it's possible it's not been properly prepared. Some "generic" tools to create a bootable USB flash drive from a CD/DVD image file don't properly set up the EFI boot loader, so you may want to try another tool. If you've got a working Linux system, use `dd`, as in `dd if=imagefile.iso of=/dev/sdc` (to create a USB flash drive at `/dev/sdc` from `imagefile.iso`). If you've got an optical drive, you could also try burning the image to an optical disc rather than use a USB flash drive.